# JavaFX controller class not working

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm really struggling to understand JavaFX controllers, my aim is to write to a TextArea to act as a log.

My code is below, but I want to be able to change values ETC from another class that I can call when needed. I have tried to create a controller class that extents Initializable but i cant get it to work. Could some one steer me in the correct direction?

I want to move the @FXML code at the bottom to another class and it update the Scene.

```
package application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Root.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,504,325);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public Thread thread = new Thread(new webimporter());

    @FXML
    public Label runningLabel;

    @FXML 
    public TextArea txtArea;

    @FXML
    void runClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        changeLabelValue("Importer running...");
        thread.start();

    }   

    @FXML
    protected void stopClick(ActionEvent event){
        changeLabelValue("Importer stopped...");
        thread.interrupt();
    }           

    @FXML
    void changeLabelValue(String newText){
        runningLabel.setText(newText);
    }

    void changeTextAreaValue(String newText1){
        txtArea.setText(newText1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't make the Application class a controller.  It's a sin.  There are other questions and answers which address this, but my search skills cannot find them at this time.

The reason it is a sin is:

1. You are only supposed to have one Application instance, and, by default, the loader will make a new instance, so you end up with two application objects.
2. Referencing the member objects is confusing, because the original launched application doesn't have the @FXML injected fields, but the loader created application instance does have @FXML inject fields.

Also, unrelated advice: Don't start trying to write multi-threaded code until you have the application at least working to the extent where it displays your UI.

A multi-threaded logger for JavaFX is in the answer to [Most efficient way to log messages to JavaFX TextArea via threads with simple custom logging frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116858/most-efficient-way-to-log-messages-to-javafx-textarea-via-threads-with-simple-cu), though unfortunately it is not straight-forward in its implementation and comes with little documentation.

---

[image: sample output]

*textlogger/Root.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="400.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="textlogger.ImportController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#run" text="Run" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stop" text="Stop" />
            <Label fx:id="runningLabel" />
         </children>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </HBox>
      <TextArea fx:id="textArea" editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

*textlogger.ImportController.java*

```
package textlogger;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ImportController {
    @FXML
    private Label runningLabel;

    @FXML
    private TextArea textArea;

    private WebImporter importer;

    @FXML
    void run(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        changeLabelValue("Importer running...");

        if (importer == null) {
            importer = new WebImporter(textArea);
            Thread thread = new Thread(
                    importer
            );
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void stop(ActionEvent event){
        changeLabelValue("Importer stopped...");
        if (importer != null) {
            importer.cancel();
            importer = null;
        }
    }           

    private void changeLabelValue(String newText){
        runningLabel.setText(newText);
    }

}
```

*textlogger.WebImporter.java*

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

import java.time.LocalTime;

public class WebImporter extends Task<Void> {

    private final TextArea textArea;

    public WebImporter(TextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                Thread.sleep(500);

                Platform.runLater(
                        () -> textArea.setText(
                                textArea.getText() + LocalTime.now() + "\n"
                        )
                );
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

*textlogger.TextLoggingSample.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextLoggingSample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Parent root = loader.load(
                getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                        "Root.fxml"
                )
            );

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can get it to display and work fine but i cant work out how to write in the TextArea from the class i have created in the thread.

Comment: When you don't provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you make me do more work to help you solve your issues.

Comment: When you cannot grasp a concept it is hard to fully explain it.

Comment: Yes, I know, asking good questions is harder than writing answers.  Hopefully the info here might assist you.

Comment: Thank you jewelsea you have solved my problem. Learning Java with no one to mentor you is not an easy job. The book I bought "Beginning Programming with Java for DUMMIES" is only so good. It taught me to use the Application class as a controller. I will not do this in the future. I managed to work out how to specify a new controller in the scene builder. You have helped me learn how to parse the TextArea into the class which has helped me no end. I don't understand the  "extends Task<Void> {" but I guess that polymorphism or one of the ways you can copy a class into your own.

Comment: If you could recommend any resources/ websites to help me on my journey I would appreciate it. Just so you know this is multi threaded as I have another thread that uses selenium to fill out a webform from a csv and prints a label out of our thermal printer and cleans up the used csv. The log thread is for the user to see which have been printed.