# lang.NullPointerException when reading resource file outside initialization method

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a program that uses a resource bundle for strings for easy translation. The structure is:

```
src/
└── main
    ├── java
    |   └── Main.java
    └── resources
        ├── Main.fxml
        ├── strings.properties
        ├── strings_en.properties
        └── strings_nl.properties
```

When I load the properties file in my `start` method (This is a JavaFX application) it works fine:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws java.io.IOException {
    resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings", new Locale("nl"));
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main.fxml"), resources);
    primaryStage.setTitle(resources.getString("title"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 1024));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I can see this by the fact that the title of the window has the correct string, as set in the properties file. Then when I try to access the same `resources` variable elsewhere, I get a `lang.NullPointerException`:

```
@FXML
private void addItem(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle(resources.getString("err.unknownItem.title")); // Throws NullPointerException
        alert.setHeaderText(resources.getString("err.unknownItem.header"));
        alert.setContentText(resources.getString("err.unknownItem.text"));

        alert.show();
    }
}
```

I tried moving the code inside the `catch`-block to the `start` method, where it works fine.

The full stacktrace is

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:178)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:216)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:246)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.addItem(Main.java:116)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: Show how `resources` is initialized in the controller.

Comment: `resources` is initialized in the `start` method, both methods are in the same class. `start` is called before `addItem`

Comment: **Always** post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: "both methods are in the same class". But they are instance methods; it's not enough for them to be in the same *class*, they must belong to the same *object*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing from the comments below the question that you are using the same class for the `Application` class and for the controller class. [Don't do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081713/javafx-controller-class-not-working). it [causes mayhem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqyon8v9XOAhXL2B4KHaaIBusQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F33303167%2Fjavafx-can-application-class-be-the-controller-class&usg=AFQjCNGSRfSMZ0YT0TJAnnd4O79dVvppYg&sig2=eEZLBHxF0uSPVe0jWsgAug).

Basically, the `start()` method is invoked on the instance of the `Application` subclass created by `launch()`. The event handler method is invoked on the instance of the controller class that is created by the `FXMLLoader`. If you use the same class for both (**don't**), then the `resources` field will be initialized in the instance created by `launch()`, but it won't be initialized in the instance created by the `FXMLLoader` (because it's a different object entirely).

Use a different class for the controller and the application.

Note that in a controller, you can define an `initialize` method which is automatically passed a reference to the resource bundle, so you can do:

```
public class Controller {

    private ResourceBundle resources ;

    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.resources = resources ;
    }

    // ..
}
```

Also note that the following, while undocumented, also seems to work:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources ;

    // ...

}
```

Here you *must* use the field name `resources`.

Comment: I never knew that was how launching an application worked, thanks! I just moved the controller to a separate class and passed the command line arguments to it, works like a charm now! Thanks!

Comment: @cascer1 No need to pass the command line arguments; see update for a couple of cleaner ways of making it work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I never mentioned this. I have some command line arguments used for setting up the database connection in the controller. I passed *those* to the controller. I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14190310/4385713) to separate the controller from the launcher and pass the arguments.

Comment: But you presumably want to pass the resource bundle to the FXMLLoader (so that you can do [resource resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution) inside the FXML file). So you would need the resource bundle before then. There's no point in looking it up in the database twice; just pass the resource bundle to the loader when you load the FXML and let the `FXMLLoader` pass it to the controller as above. Sounds like you are making the code more convoluted than it needs to be. But anyway.. I suppose if it works...

Comment: The resources and database are completely separate. The resources are indeed passed to the FXMLLoader by the launcher.  There are two database connections in the resources, a local development connection and a production connection. I can switch between them using a command line argument. The switching happens in the controller, where the connection is established.

Comment: Ah, ok, got it. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings", new Locale("nl"));
```

to your `addItem(ActionEvent e)` method

Comment: Sort of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? The resource bundle should be specified at startup time.

Comment: yeah, but maybe his is loosed it somewhere =). maybe `resource` is `null`... need to check that.

Comment: Check it with `if (resources==null) { throw new IllegalStateException("resources is null"); }`. But it's pretty clear that's the case anyway.