# What's causing my StackOverflowError

Tags: java, javafx, stack-overflow

So, I'm getting a StackOverflowError (Unwrapped from  a InvocationTargetException), and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
package gui;
import errorhandling.ErrorLogBook;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUIRouter extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Application.launch(GUIRouter.class, (String[])null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getCause().toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void start (Stage primaryStage)
{
    try
    {
        StackPane page = (StackPane) FXMLLoader.load(GUIRouter.class.getResource("LoginScreen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorLogBook.logReport(e);
    }
}
```

It fails at the first try block with:

```
Application.launch(GUIRouter.class, (String[])null);
```

This is a FXML application that I'm building with NetBeans and JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0

Any ideas about why my code keeps crashing?

Comment: A StackOverflow generally has a section that just repeats over and over, if that is the case it'd be helpful if you provided it.

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch clauses so that you see the full (or as full as it can be for a stack overflow) stack traces on the console...

Comment: Also show your `ErrorLogBook` class, perhaps that contains the stack overflow?

Comment: 1. As previously requested, post the repeating part of the stack trace. 2. Remove the `ErrorLogBook` call and replace it with a regular `e.printStackTrace()` to ensure the `ErrorLogBook` is not part of the problem. 3. It's probably inadvisable to pass `null` as the parameter list; pass an empty array instead (which you can do simply with `Application.launch(GUIRouter.class);`). 4. Post the controller class for the FXML file.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your .fxml in `"LoginScreen.fxml"` has GuiRouter defined as its controller, which it then creates through reflection. My guess is that during that creation it ends up calling `start(..)` creating a loop.

Comment: And if this is the case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081713/javafx-controller-class-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303167/javafx-can-application-class-be-the-controller-class

Comment: @Kiskae nice guess!

Answer (score 0):

Without having the .fxml file and/or the stack trace, I (see no way but to ) guess the main cause of the exception in exactly the same way as Kiskae did. 
However, why you do not replace the line

```
Application.launch(GUIRouter.class, (String[])null);
```

with the more simpler form

```
Application.launch(args);
```

Or at least

```
Application.launch(args, new String[0]);
```

To see if the exception still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package gui;
import errorhandling.ErrorLogBook;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GUIRouter extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            StackPane page = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/LoginScreen.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ErrorLogBook.logReport(e);
        }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the responses!
However, after playing around with it, I have found the root of the problem.
I replaced

```
StackPane page = (StackPane) FXMLLoader.load(GUIRouter.class.getResource("LoginScreen.fxml"));
```

with

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginScreen.fxml"));
```

and now it's working just fine.

Comment: This is no use whatsoever to anyone else unless you put enough information in your question to show why this is happening.

Comment: I still don't know why it was happening, or why that fixed it.