# JavaFX Label doesn't set text

Tags: javafx, label, scenebuilder

I'm doing a Calendar with JavaFX SceneBuilder.

I declare my Label on my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
//Calendar used
public Calendar cal;
//variables for get the number of week+current year
public static int weeks, year;
@FXML
//Text areas for the 4 weeks column
public TextArea week1,week2,week3,week4;
@FXML 
//4 control Buttons
public Button prev,next,next2,prev2, start;
@FXML
//Labels
public Label lab1;
```

And the method which I'm trying to set text is this one:

```
public void ClickStart (ActionEvent event){
    lab1=new Label();
    lab1.setText("hola");
    cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    week1.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    week2.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    week3.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    weeks= cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    week4.setText("Week " + Integer.toString(weeks) + " " + Integer.toString(year));
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -3);
    }
```

I include also my .fmxl file if necessary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.Main">
  <children>
    <GridPane>
      <children>
        <GridPane>
          <children>
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Monday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Tuesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Wednesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Thursday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Friday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Saturday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Sunday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Monday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Tuesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Wednesday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Thursday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Friday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Saturday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextArea editable="false" mouseTransparent="false" prefWidth="200.0" text="Sunday" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Button id="prev" fx:id="prev2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickMinus" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="prev" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Button fx:id="next" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickPlus" prefHeight="29.999900000002526" prefWidth="70.00009999999747" text="next" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Button fx:id="next2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickPlus" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="next" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Button fx:id="prev" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickMinus" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="prev" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week1" prefWidth="200.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week2" prefWidth="200.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week4" prefWidth="200.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label  id= "lab1" fx:id="lab1" prefHeight="40.000099999997474" prefWidth="150.0" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label minHeight="14.0" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="533.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="87.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label prefHeight="44.0" prefWidth="139.0" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextArea fx:id="week3" prefHeight="100.00009999999747" prefWidth="70.0" text="Week x Year x" wrapText="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Button fx:id="start" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickStart" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="70.0" text="Start" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
          </children>
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
  </children>
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

The problem is that when I run the application and I press my Start button, the label doesn't change to the text given(By default is on 'empty').

Comment: You do not need to create new object. Please try to set only texts of objects created on fxml file. As a brief delete `lab1=new Label();` line.

Comment: Also, [don't use the `Application` class as the class for the controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081713/javafx-controller-class-not-working).

Comment: Thanks, it was perfectly working after deleting that line!

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have the solution in the comments, I'll just give you a short explanation of why deleting

```
lab1 = new Label();
```

solved the problem.

When you declared `lab1` in your fxml file you told the JavaFX `FXMLLoader` to instantiate this`Label` for you. So essentially it did the `new Label()` call for you. It then passes a reference to the `Label` that it created to the variable `lab1` of your class `Main`. When you changed `lab1` to reference your newly created label in `lab1 = new Label();` you overwrote the reference to the label that is in your UI. That new label is not yet added to any `Scene` and is not shown, so when you change its text, the change is not visible.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. :)