# JavaFX - What type of view is this that displays a list?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to display a long list of urls like in this video

[image]

At first I thought it was a ListView so I tried building one

```
<ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="128.0" 
prefHeight="172.0" prefWidth="390.0" focusTraversable="false"/>
```

```
@FXML
ListView<String> listView;
```

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList (
                "Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App", "Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App", "Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App", "Single", "Double", "Suite", "Family App");
        listView.setItems(items);
}
```

But my mines doesn't quite look like that.

[image]

What type of view do they use where it doesn't allow row selection or have a checkered pattern?

Comment: It might be a `TextArea`. But note you can style the `ListView` to not have the "zebra lines" and also to make it so selected/focused items are not rendered as selected/focused. Using the `ListView` would be better if you have thousands+ lines.

Comment: I've gotten the listview to disable the zebra lines with ```<ListView style="-fx-control-inner-background-alt: -fx-control-inner-background;``` But I'm trying to figure out how to disable the item selection. Do I use the child fxml class ```<ListCell``` to disable the selected items? There's no attribute like ```selectable="false"```

Comment: I guess making the background the same as the listview disables the focus color ```.list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background ;
}``` not sure how to do it otherwise

Comment: Yes, I was thinking you'd do it via CSS. Though of course this only removes the appearance of selection/focus; items will still be selected/focused when the user e.g. clicks on them.

Comment: [even/odd pseudo classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#indexedcell) on cells control the zebra pattern. Search JavaFX source for moderna.css to see how they are applied. But if you just want to remove the zebra, you can set the background coloring for all cells to null: see the [log-view.css file in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24140252/1155209) as an example.

Comment: I don’t advise styling using inline styles in fxml, instead use style classes in css.

Comment: If you have lots of info in comments to add to the question, don’t do it comments, edit the question instead.

Comment: Note that this can’t be a TextArea, because text in text area can’t have multiple colors (except for selected text, which is not what this is).

Comment: looks like Swing .. to disable selection, null the models