# Odd Behavior javafx.concurrent.Task

Tags: java, javafx

I created an app to answer a question. For the most part, the app runs correctly, but I am getting some strange behavior out of `ScheduledService` `updateMessage`. My understanding of `udpateMessage` could be wrong, which could be leading me astray. My understanding is that `updateMessage` should update `messageProperty` every time `updateMessage` is called. In this case, that should be every three seconds. In this app, that is not happening. `updateValue` and `System.out.println` are both updating as expected. Is this faulty behavior, or is my thinking wrong about how `updateMessage` works?

### Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;

public class App extends Application {
    
    static List<MyNotification> myNotifications = new ArrayList();
    static FakeDatabaseHandler fakeDatabaseHandler = new FakeDatabaseHandler();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        Button btnGenerateNotification = new Button("Generate!");
        btnGenerateNotification.setOnAction(actionEvent ->{            
             fakeDatabaseHandler.addFakeNotificationsToDb();
        });

        Label lblUpdateMessage = new Label("Update Message: ");
        
        ScheduledService<List<MyNotification>> checkForScheduledService = new CheckForNotificationsScheduledService();
        checkForScheduledService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));
        checkForScheduledService.messageProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null)
            {
                lblUpdateMessage.setText("Update Message: " + newValue);
            }
        });
        
        checkForScheduledService.valueProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue != null && !newValue.isEmpty())
            {
                myNotifications.clear();
                myNotifications.addAll(newValue);
                checkForScheduledService.cancel();
                
                AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
                checkForScheduledService.cancel();
                Timeline threeSecondsWonder = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3),  event -> {    
                        MyNotification myNotification = myNotifications.get(index.getAndIncrement());
                        Notifications.create().title(myNotification.department()+ " - " + myNotification.title()).text(myNotification.message()).hideAfter(Duration.seconds(3)).showWarning();
                    })
                );
                threeSecondsWonder.setCycleCount(myNotifications.size());
                threeSecondsWonder.play();
                threeSecondsWonder.setOnFinished((t) -> {
                    checkForScheduledService.restart();
                });
            }
        });
        checkForScheduledService.start();
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane(new VBox(btnGenerateNotification, lblUpdateMessage));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        stage.setTitle("Facilities");
        stage.show();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    private static class CheckForNotificationsScheduledService extends ScheduledService<List<MyNotification>> {

    @Override
    protected Task<List<MyNotification>> createTask() {
        return new Task<List<MyNotification>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<MyNotification> call() throws Exception {
                List<MyNotification> fakeNotificationList = fakeDatabaseHandler.getFakeNotificationsFromDB();
                
                System.out.println("Checking for notifications. Notifications Found: " + fakeNotificationList.size());
                updateMessage("Checking for notifications. Notifications Found: " + fakeNotificationList.size());             
                updateValue(fakeNotificationList);                
                
                return fakeNotificationList; 
            }
        };
    }
  }
}
```

### FakeDatabaseHandler

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

/**
 *
 * @author Sed
 */
public class FakeDatabaseHandler {
    private final List<MyNotification> fakeDBData = new ArrayList();    
    
    public FakeDatabaseHandler() {}
    
    public void addFakeNotificationsToDb(){
        List<String> departmentList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
              
        for(int i = 0; i < ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 6); i++)
        {
            int notificationID = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 1000000);
            fakeDBData.add(new MyNotification("Department: " + departmentList.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(4)), "Title " + notificationID, "Message: " + notificationID));
        }
    }
    
    public List<MyNotification> getFakeNotificationsFromDB(){
        List<MyNotification> returnList = new ArrayList(fakeDBData);
        fakeDBData.clear();
        
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

### MyNotification

```
public record MyNotification(String department, String title, String message) {}
```

### Module-Info

```
module com.mycompany.javafxsimpletest {  
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    exports com.mycompany.javafxsimpletest;
}
```

### Output

[image]

### Tech Info

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 18
Java: 19.0.2; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.2+7-jvmci-22.3-b12
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 19.0.2+7-jvmci-22.3-b12
System: Windows 11 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
```

Comment: From the Javadoc: **Updates the message property. Calls to updateMessage are coalesced and run later on the FX application thread, so calls to updateMessage, even from the FX Application thread, may not necessarily result in immediate updates to this property, and intermediate message values may be coalesced to save on event notifications.**  And BTW, it's `javafx.concurrent.Task#updateMessage()` not `ScheduledService`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here.  Why do you restart the scheduled service every three seconds? `threeSecondsWonder.setOnFinished((t) -> { checkForScheduledService.restart(); });`.  The service is already scheduled to execute its task every five seconds `checkForScheduledService.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(5));`.  Also why cancel the service `checkForScheduledService.cancel();`? Why not just start the service and leave it alone?  There seem to be numerous errors and misconceptions here.

Comment: One other problem here (perhaps the fundamental problem?) is thread liveness. You are updating `fakeDatabaseHandler.fakeDbData` from the FX Application Thread (via the button's event handler) but you are accessing it from the background thread (in the task created by the service). Since there is no synchronization on `fakeDbData` there is no guarantee one thread will ever see changes made in the other thread.

Comment: @JimGarrison, Thanks for clearing up `javafx.concurrent.Task#updateMessage()`.  In the past, when I used `Task#updateMessage()`, `Labels` would update as expected. Even if updates are not immediate, I expect to see the updates in a reasonable amount of time. I haven't seen any updates.

Comment: Some quick testing shows that the message gets reset to `null` once the task has completed. So the `updateMessage()` call results in a call being scheduled via `Platform.runLater()` to update the Task's message property to the current value (of an internally-held `AtomicReference<String>`). Then the task immediately exits, causing another `Platform.runLater(...)` call which updates the value to the results of the task and the message to null. (The latter *might* be coalesced with the earlier call, but I don't think that's the implementation.) The label's text is only ever `null`.

Comment: @jewelsea, I was thinking that once the service finds message(s), I should stop looking for new messages until after the current messages have been processed.  I thought the following code restarts the services after all of the messages are processed, but you pointed out that the service restarts after each notification is processed. This could be causing the issue. I will check once I get back to work.

Comment: @James_D, Thanks; I will try to see what happens if I synchronize things.

Comment: This seems a bit like a producer/consumer problem.  Such problems can be solved using a [deque](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html).  For instance as in this [logging framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116858/most-efficient-way-to-log-messages-to-javafx-textarea-via-threads-with-simple-cu).

Comment: @jewelsea, Thanks. I figured it out and learned a lot from you all in the process!

Comment: @JimGarrison, Thanks! I learned a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note there are two messages: one belonging to the tasks that are created, and one belonging to the service. When the service is in the process of running a task, its message is bound to the task's message, but once the task completes the service's message is reset to null.

Consequently, your task sets its message (and consequently the service's message), based on the values generated by the button press, but then the task immediately exits, causing the service's message to be set to null.

Note that these two changes may be coalesced, depending on the implementation of the service. But even if they are not, the change to null will immediately follow the change explicitly coded in the task, before the next frame is rendered. So in either case the label will only ever display null text.

There are various other issues with your code, as pointed out in the comments below the question (the model class is not threadsafe, but is accessed from multiple threads, and the `ScheduledService` is repeatedly restarted, making it redundant).

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what is going on. Though I do have tons of other issues with this code, the core issue for the `updateMessage` was that, as written, it appeared to be always null. I put `updateMessage` in a loop, and I could see the changes before it went back to null. This all stemmed from my not understanding how `ScheduledService` works. I thought it starts, runs, and only stops on error or when someone cancels it. It actually stops and restarts each X amount of time passed. I finally looked at the JavaDocs.